# Reassemble function that has its control flow chopped so that it can be decompiled by IDA

Tags: ida, deobfuscation, decompile

I try to decompile a function that is obfuscated by having split 
up the controlflow into asmblocks scattered around the .text section 
and connected by "jmpq" jumps.

```
<func1>:
0:    insn..
1:    jmpq xx100
2:    callq sub
3:    jmpq  xx104
...
<nonfunc>:
..
xx100: insn...
xx101: jmpq 2
..
xx104: insn 
...
```

Is there a tool/plugin that can reassemble the function code by following the jmpq blocks and appending the chunks? I guess it is not that
trivial because you also have to account for relative offsets and patch
relocation sections, etc. .

Comment: If you are pressing <kbd>P</kbd> on the function start what do you see ? (Save the database before conducting this experiment)

Comment: I dont have any action linked to the key "P" in IDA. What action should key "P" trigger?

Comment: It is create function. As far as I know it may handle such a functions in significant part of cases

Comment: I am probably not helping - but this strikes me as a typical graph isomorphism question. Perhaps tools like Binnavi could help.

Comment: Tryping to write it myself: https://github.com/eiselekd/perlx8664 .